# When (day, month, year) did Avshalom son of king David die?

Tags: sources-mekorot, parshanut-torah-comment, death, king-david, samuel-shmuel-book-of

When (day, month, year) did Avshalom son of king David die?
Please cite a source as to exactly when this happened.

> [II Samuel 18:15 And there circled about ten young men who were Joab's
> armor bearers, and they struck Absalom, and killed him.](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15878/showrashi/true)

Answer (score 3):

Only a (very) partial answer, but  [סדר הדורות](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46817&st=&pgnum=128) puts it in the year 2921 from Creation.   (Top of right column).   Technically it states that his rule started on that year, but then again, he wasn't king very long.

Actual quote:

> אבשלום מלך ב"א תתקכ"א, שלש שנים קודם מות אביו

My translation:

> Avshalom ruled in the year 2921 [to Creation], three years before his father's death.

Comment: can you quote the actual sentence that says that?

Comment: @ninamag Added.

Comment: is there any indication on what season he died, assuming we do not know the month and/or date.